# connect a pi Raspberry to a relay

Tags: raspberry-pi, python-3.7, raspberry-pi4

hello I have a Raspberry pi 4 and wanted to connect to a relay but I can not find information on how to connect a Raspberry pi 4 and the relay equal to the photo someone can me I will then program in python, someone can help me. Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Raspberry Pi.SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You can normally find sample applications on the website of the providers of these boards, ie adafruit or joy-it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have built your relay and setup all the wiring you can just create a simple python script to use the relay:

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)

time.sleep(0.25)

GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: I wanted connection cables to Raspberry pi, but thank